# How to redirect a specific user to a specific page? I am not talking about after logging-in

Tags: php, wordpress, developer-tools

I use WordPress.

I know how to redirect a user to a specific page after logging in. But let's say they have already logged-in and they click  specific URL, they should be redirected to another.

Sample:
USER A
The user has already logged-in.
He clicks domainname.com/my-account
He will be redirected to domainname.com/profile1

USER B
The user has already logged-in.
He clicks domainname.com/my-account
He will be redirected to domainname.com/profile2

All of them click the domainname.com/my-account but they have to be redirected to a different page.

This redirection is per user. Is there a way to do this in function.php?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using the global `$_SERVER`-variable.

But in order to provide you a full answer, then I would need to know, how you distinquish, if a user should see `/profile1` or `profile2`. Is it all women that sees `/profile1`, or all administrators or all those names 'Jim'?

This is a version, where the user with the username `jim` will see `profile1`, - and everybody else will see `profile2`.

```
function custom20180126_redirect() {

  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  $target_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if( $target_uri == '/my-account' ){
    if( $user->data->user_login == 'jim' ){
      wp_redirect( '/profile1' );
    } else {
      wp_redirect( '/profile2' );  
    } 
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom20180126_redirect' );
```

Pop that in your `functions.php`...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Zeth. Appreciate it. However, this seems to be not working on my end.

Comment: Hello. Yup, nothing happens. It stays in the page and the redirection did not go through.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. In order to provide you a full answer, I would need to know how you distinquish, if a user should see `/profile1` or `profile2`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the job done

```php
<?php

function my_custom_user_redirect()
{
    // Get the current page\object
    $the_page = sanitize_post($GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object());
    // Get the Slug
    $slug = $the_page->post_name;
    // Check if the slug is my-account
    if ($slug === 'my-account') {
        // Get the user
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        // if the user is logged in
        if ($user->ID) {
            // Set the url: https://sample.test/profile1
            $url = get_site_url() . 'profile' . $user->ID;
            // Redirect
            wp_safe_redirect($url);
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_user_redirect');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Enrique. Appreciate it. But it did not work.